# CefSharp : Is there a handler of left click inside the ChromiumWebBrowser?

Tags: c#, .net, chromium, cefsharp

Im trying to disable any clicking activity (whether left click or right click) inside my ChromiumWebBrowser webview. As of now I can handle the Right Click part via IContextMenuHandler's OnContextMenuDismissed which works perfectly but I can't seem to find a solution on the left click part. Any idea about this? I'm still new to CefSharp and any help or anyone who can enlighten me will do. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `WPF` or `WinForms`?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am using WinForms.

Comment: Unfortunately no handler in `WinForms`.

Comment: Oh I see. Is there an alternative way you could suggest to me? Thanks! My main goal is for the user to be on one webpage only and he/she can only scroll through the webpage but cannot click to it.

Comment: You can cancel navigation using OnBeforeBrowse, prevent links from doing anything. To hook the mouse you have to dig through the child windows to find the one receiving the mouse events and hook it with a NatveWindow.

Comment: Will try @amaitland . Thanks!

Comment: There is a rough example in the WinForms example project on GitHub, just search the source for nativewindow

Comment: Hi @amaitland , btw if in WPF what handler could I use for this? Im still in the learning process of what you have suggested me back then so Ill try to recode in WPF as a backup.

Comment: Hi @amaitland, any update about this? your link does not work anymore.. Thanks.

https://github.com/amaitland/CefSharp/tree/example/onbeforebrowse

Comment: There's no specific handler,  just override standard WPF mouse events. No idea what link you are referring.

Comment: Hi @amaitland , the original thread came from this link :

[link](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/354)

Where you answered someones question of jerrymats which is:



*I need a way to cancel the navigation if the url matches a predefined condition.

Example: a page has a few internal links and 1 link pointing to www.yahoo.com. When user clicks the yahoo link, I don't want user to navigate to yahoo. Instead, I want to pop up a message box and then cancel the navigation. I did this with IE based web browser control. But want to migrate to CEF3.*

Comment: Here is the link of the image of what im talking about : https://imgur.com/0igV6pY

Comment: The API doc is at http://cefsharp.github.io/api/ you can search it for OnBeforeBrowse

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the click event using javascript and if you need anything from C# code, then create a callback object and register it using `RegisterJsObject`. Then in js code, you can refer to the callback object.

In the following example, I've browsed google and dynamically attached `click` event handler to all `a` tags. Then when a click on `a` tag happen, I've handled the click using `bool a_Click(string)` method of the `CallbackObject`.

Then I've checked if the link is anything but the gmail link, it will stop browsing:

```
public class CallbackObjectForJs {
    public bool handleAClick(string url) {
        if (!url.ToLower().StartsWith("https://mail.google.com"))
            return true; //cancel event
        else
            return false;
    }
}

ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);
    CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;
    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(
        "https://www.google.com");
    browser.RegisterJsObject("callbackObj", new CallbackObjectForJs());
    browser.LoadingStateChanged += Browser_LoadingStateChanged;
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    Controls.Add(browser);
}

private void Browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender,
    LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (!e.IsLoading) {
        var script = @"
            var data = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            Array.from(data).forEach((a) => {
                a.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                    if(callbackObj.handleAClick(this.href)) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            });";
        browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've recently added a new feature that can be used for simplify this type of scenario see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2775 for details.

Comment: I didn't notice on first read thorough that you are using `RegisterJsObject` which will likely be removed in the not too distant future. Using the `sync` version (which `RegisterJsObject` is a helper function for) is strongly discouraged, the `sync` version will remain for legacy applications, basically anyone upgrading. Anyone developing an application should use the `async` version or the `CefSharp.PostMessage` function I've linked to. I understand that the `javascript event handler` is a sync function and it's not possible to call `preventDefault` in an async fashion.

Comment: @amaitland Thanks for the comments, I'll check the links :)